# Full justification fails

Tags: line-breaking

I am now writing my thesis and have a problem occurring in some pages. The problem regards full justification of text. LaTeX sometimes fails to fully justify text and break lines. 
In other words, the text steps into the right margin. Please, how to solve this troubling problem? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem.

Comment: A possibility would be to use `\sloppy` at the begin of the paragraph where the text run in the margin and use `\fussy` for after the paragraph, see also  http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/73586/16895

Answer (score 3):

Using the [`microtype`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/microtype) package will help you with that, it tweaks hyphenation here and there and results in fewer overfull boxes (that's what these words sticking into the right margin are called).

Also, make sure you loaded [`babel`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/babel) with the language option appropriate for your document. Typically, I'd load `babel` before `microtype`.